# can't convert online gif to mp4 video using ffmpeg

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I am trying to turn this gif into mp4 video using ffmpeg but it is not working
https://media.giphy.com/media/H7T8UdGOvOQiDf9QXj/giphy.gif

I tried this code

```
-i https://media.giphy.com/media/H7T8UdGOvOQiDf9QXj/giphy.gif output.mp4
```

also I tried this code

```
-f gif -i https://media.giphy.com/media/H7T8UdGOvOQiDf9QXj/giphy.gif output.mp4
```

in both cases it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg provides a helpful error:

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls or securetransport enabled.
```

Solution is to enable gnutls support in ffmpeg (`--enable-gnutls`). Read about potential problem regarding openssl: [How to enable ffmpeg openssl in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958267/1109017).

Alternative solution is to download the GIF separately, then run ffmpeg on the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Giphy allows you to share gif as mp4. There is a "share" icon that allows you to copy the mp4 link.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, as of today, you've to use this package in `pubspec.yaml`

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl: 5.1.0
```

`https-gpl` package already has `gnutls`

See https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Packages for more.