# How to enable ffmpeg openssl in Flutter

Tags: ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I want to convert https using ffmpeg but I have to enable openssl in configuration .. how can I do that in flutter ?

Comment: Is flutter just using the `ffmpeg` executable?

Comment: no it is used within package 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

## openssl is problematic

- FFmpeg supports several HTTPS libraries: openssl, gnutls, libtls, and mbedtls.
- openssl and libtls are considered to be non-free due to their licenses, and are therefore incompatible with the GPL. As most distributors of ffmpeg enable features requiring the GPL license you won't easily find ffmpeg with openssl or libtls support.

## Use gnutls or mbedtls instead

From [pub.dev - flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg):

> flutter_ffmpeg provides eight packages that include different sets of
> external libraries. These packages are named according to the external
> libraries included in them.

The packages that enable gnutls for flutter_ffmpeg are: https, https-gpl, full, and full-gpl. Using any of these will provide HTTPS support.

See the [instructions on how to enable these packages](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg#21-packages).

Comment: I am having trouble with using the FFmpeg filter in the flutter application, can you please take a look at it? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045090/flutter-ffmpeg-error-option-not-found-when-using-filter)